# How to add a mutable list as a column of a dataframe using withColumn function in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am actually looking to add a new column from a mutable list in my existing dataframe using with column function of scala, can some one please help

This is what I was trying to do but it didn't work for me

```
val list1=mutable.MutableList[String]()
val list2=mutable.MutableList[String]()
list1+=convertIntToStringBase(30,account,9)  // Applying some transformation to list1 
DF.withColumn("New_col",lit(list1))   // Adding the elements of the list as a new column in a dataframe
```

Error Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.mutable.MutableList MutableList
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

you can find in Spark 2.2 typedLit to support Seq, Map, and Tuples

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit
    
    df.withColumn("some_array", typedLit(Seq(1, 2, 3)))
    df.withColumn("some_struct", typedLit(("foo", 1, 0.3)))
    df.withColumn("some_map", typedLit(Map("key1" -> 1, "key2" -> 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer , but I am just looking simply to translate the elements of the single dimension list into a single column of a dataframe, the above code seems irrelevant to me for my use case